# Standard Lightning Icon not rendering properly

Tags: lightning, icon

Notice the first "Utility:success" icon. Why is my icon background is blurred ?

Below code renders the image as shown in picture.

```
<div class="slds-box slds-theme_success slds-theme_alert-texture">

                            <p> <span> <lightning:icon iconName="utility:success" size="small" class="slds-p-right--medium" /> </span><span>Opportunity <lightning:formattedUrl value="{!notif.Id}" label="{!notif.Name}" /> on Account </span>
                                <span><lightning:formattedUrl value="{!notif.AccountId}" label="{!notif.Account.Name}" /></span>
                                <span> and Status {!notif.StageName}</span>
                                <span> on  {!notif.LastModifiedDate}</span> </p>
                        </div>
```

[image: Rendered utility:success]

But in lightning design system the image is rendered with a bright background in the second picture
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your icon variant to success.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/example

Comment: It worked. Thanks!